PSF Matching Images from different filters
I have a fits images corresponding to different filters of JWST. I want to make sure they are PSF matched for accurate photometric color measurements by using SExtractor. I wanted to match them to F444W-band images whose typical FWHM of the PSF is 0.16 arc seconds , the largest of the NIRCam multiband image.
I have taken the PSF for each filter from webbpsf as,
filters = ['F115W', 'F150W', 'F200W', 'F277W', 'F356W', 'F410M', 'F444W']
psfs = {}
    for f in filters:
        nc = webbpsf.NIRCam()
        nc.filter = f
        psf = nc.calc_psf(fov_arcsec=5,oversample=4)
        psf_data = psf[0].data
        psfs[f] = psf_data

Then since they were having different shapes , I converted them into same shape as,
resized_psfs = {}
for f, psf in psfs.items():
    zoom_factors = np.array(target_shape) / np.array(psf.shape)
    resized_psf = zoom(psf, zoom_factors, order=3)  # cubic interpolation
    resized_psfs[f] = resized_psf

Then I used the create_matching_kernel option from photutils make a matching kernal.
from photutils.psf import CosineBellWindow, create_matching_kernel
window = CosineBellWindow(alpha=0.35)
kernel = create_matching_kernel(psf_to_match, target_psf, window=window)

But I am not getting proper result as expected.
I am sharing the plots that I got ,

and the matching kernal was ,

What could be wrong here ?
And finally for convolving the images , can i use convolve from astropy.convolution
